# Trying to scrape and segregated into Headings and Contents. The problem is that both have same class and tags, How to segregate?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to web scrape http://www.intermediary.natwest.com/intermediary-solutions/lending-criteria.html segregating into 2 parts Heading and Content, The problem is that both have same class and tags. Other than using regex and hard coding, How to distinguish and extract into 2 columns in excel?

In the picture(https://ibb.co/8X5xY9C) or in the website link provided, Bold(Except Alphabet Letters(A) and later 'back to top' ) represents Heading and Explanation(non-bold just below bold) represents the content(Content even consists of 'li' and 'ul' blocks later in the site, which should come under respective Heading)

```
#Code to Start With
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "http://www.intermediary.natwest.com/intermediary-solutions/lending-criteria.html";
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")  
Heading = soup.findAll('strong') 
content = soup.findAll('div', {"class": "comp-rich-text"})
```

Output Excel looks something Link this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsMmm.png

Comment: Do you want to achieve a result like that in your final image or what?

Comment: Yes https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsMmm.png Exactly similar to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've thought about it a little more and thought of a better solution. Rather than "crowd" my initial solution, I chose to add a 2nd solution here:

So thinking about it again, and following my logic of splitting the html by the headlines (essentially breaking it up where we find `<strong>` tags), I choose to convert to strings using `.prettify()`, and then split on those specific strings/tags and read back into BeautifulSoup to pull the text. From what I see, it looks like it hasn't missed anything, but you'll have to search through the dataframe to double check:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


url = 'http://www.intermediary.natwest.com/intermediary-solutions/lending-criteria.html'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

sections = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'accordion-section-content'})

results = {}
for section in sections:
    splits = section.prettify().split('<strong>')
    for each in splits:
        try:
            headline, content = each.split('</strong>')[0].strip(), each.split('</strong>')[1]
            headline = BeautifulSoup(headline, 'html.parser').text.strip()
            content = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser').text.strip()

            content_split = content.split('\n')
            content = ' '.join([ text.strip() for text in content_split if text != ''])

            results[headline] = content
        except:
            continue

df = pd.DataFrame(results.items(), columns = ['Headings','Content'])
df.to_csv('C:/test.csv', index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
                                         Headings                                            Content
0                                Age requirements  Applicants must be at least 18 years old at th...
1                                   Affordability  Our affordability calculator is the same one u...
2                        Agricultural restriction  The only acceptable agricultural tie is where ...
3         Annual percentage rate of charge (APRC)  The APRC is all fees associated with the mortg...
4                                  Adverse credit  We consult credit reference agencies to look a...
5                          Applicants (number of)           The maximum number of applicants is two.
6                          Armed Forces personnel  Unsecured personal loans are only acceptable f...
7                                    Back to back  Back to back is typically where the vendor has...
8                       Customer funded purchase:  when the customer has funded the purchase usin...
9                                       Bridging:  residential mortgage applications where the cu...
10                                     Inherited:  a recently inherited property where the benefi...
11                                       Porting:  where a fixed/discounted rate was ported to a ...
12                          Repossessed property:  where the vendor is the mortgage lender in pos...
13                                 Part exchange:  where the vendor is a large national house bui...
14                                Bank statements  We accept internet bank statements in paper fo...
15                                          Bonus  For guaranteed bonuses we will consider an ave...
16              British National working overseas  Applicants must be resident in the UK. Applica...
17                           Builder's Incentives  The maximum amount of acceptable incentive is ...
18                           Buy-to-let (purpose)  A buy-to-let mortgage can be used for:  Purcha...
19                                Capital Raising  - Acceptable purposes  permanent home improvem...
20                     Buy-to-let (affordability)  Buy to Let affordability must be assessed usin...
21              Buy-to-let (eligibility criteria)  The property must be in England, Scotland, Wal...
22             Definition of a portfolio landlord  We define a portfolio landlord as a customer w...
23                              Carer's Allowance  Carer's Allowance is paid to people aged 16 or...
24                                       Cashback  Where a mortgage product includes a cashback f...
25                              Casual employment  Contract/agency workers with income paid throu...
26                     Certification of documents  When submitting copies of documents, please en...
27                                  Child Benefit  We can accept up to 100% of working tax credit...
28                                Childcare costs  We use the actual amount the customer has decl...
29   When should childcare costs not be included?  There are a number of situations where childca...
..                                            ...                                                ...
108                                 Shared equity  We lend on the Government-backed shared equity...
109                              Shared ownership  We do not lend against Shared Ownership proper...
110                              Solicitors' fees  We have a panel of solicitors for our fees ass...
111                             Source of deposit  We reserve the right to ask for proof of depos...
112                      Sole trader/partnerships  We will take an average of the last two years'...
113                        Standard variable rate  A standard variable rate  (SVR) is a type of v...
114                                 Student loans  Repayment of student loans is dependent on rec...
115                                        Tenure  Acceptable property tenure: Feuhold, Freehold,...
116                                          Term  Minimum term is 3 years  Residential - Maximum...
117                     Unacceptable income types  The following forms of income are classed as u...
118                        Bereavement allowance:  paid to widows, widowers or surviving civil pa...
119                Employee benefit trusts (EBT):  this is a tax mitigation scheme used in conjun...
120                                     Expenses:  not acceptable as they're paid to reimburse pe...
121                              Housing Benefit:  payment of full or partial contribution to cla...
122                               Income Support:  payment for people on low incomes, working les...
123                       Job Seeker's Allowance:  paid to people who are unemployed or working 1...
124                                      Stipend:  a form of salary paid for internship/apprentic...
125                           Third Party Income:  earned by a spouse, partner, parent who are no...
126                             Universal Credit:  only certain elements of the Universal Credit ...
127                              Universal Credit  The Standard Allowance element, which is the n...
128               Valuations: day one instruction  We are now instructing valuations on day one f...
129                         Valuation instruction  A valuation will be automatically instructed w...
130                                Valuation fees  A valuation will always be obtained using a pa...
131                                  Please note:  W  hen upgrading the free valuation for a home...
132                       Adding fees to the loan  Product fees are the only fees which can be ad...
133                                   Product fee  This fee is paid when the mortgage is arranged...
134                                Working abroad  Previously, we required applicants to be  empl...
135                                  Acceptable -  We may consider applications from people who: ...
136                              Not acceptable -  We will not consider applications from  people...
137                Working and Family Tax Credits  We can accept up to 100% of Working Tax Credit...

[138 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: actually, just did that about a moment ago, just didn't update the Output. I also figured the heavy lifting is done, @PavanSN can fix any of the cosmetics.

Comment: Thank you So much for the answer, I can definitely fix cosmetics.

Comment: Did it seem to give the right output? I was looking it through and seemed everything lined up. This one was a tricky one.

Comment: Hey, Now the website structure is changed, Now the <strong> tag is not common anymore, So how can it be scrapped? Have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: SEE OTHER SOLUTION PROVIDED**

It's tricky. I tried to essentially to grab the headings, then use those to grab all the text after the heading, and that proceeds the next heading. The code below is a little messy, and requires some cleaning up, but hopefully gets you to a point to work with it or get you moving in the right direction:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re

url = 'http://www.intermediary.natwest.com/intermediary-solutions/lending-criteria.html'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

sections = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'accordion-section-content'})
results = {}
for section in sections:
    headlines = section.find_all('strong')
    headlines = [each.text for each in headlines ]

    for i, headline in enumerate(headlines):
        if headline != headlines[-1]:
            next_headline = headlines[i+1]
        else:
            next_headline = ''
        try:
            find_content = section(text=headline)[0].parent.parent.find_next_siblings()
            if ':' in headline and 'Gifted deposit' not in headline and 'Help to Buy' not in headline:
                content = section(text=headline)[0].parent.nextSibling
                results[headline] = content.strip()
                break

        except:
            find_content = section(text=re.compile(headline))[0].parent.parent.find_next_siblings()
        if find_content == []:
            try:
                find_content = section(text=headline)[0].parent.parent.parent.find_next_siblings()
            except:
                find_content = section(text=re.compile(headline))[0].parent.parent.parent.find_next_siblings()

        content = []
        for sibling in find_content:
            if next_headline not in sibling.text or headline == headlines[-1]:
                content.append(sibling.text)
            else:
                content = '\n'.join(content)
                results[headline.strip()] = content.strip()
                break
        if headline == headlines[-1]:
            content = '\n'.join(content)
            results[headline] = content.strip()

df = pd.DataFrame(results.items())
```